# Shopify Customer Login issue by mobile buy SDK on ios

Tags: ios, shopify, shopify-app

I am developing a mobile app Builder on Shopify. But Shopify doesn't provide any store back API for **customer Login**. So I use mobile-buy-sdk for ios for customer login.

(I have installed mobile-buy-sdk on ios app and try to get access token by GraphQL)

In mobile-buy-sdk I am getting some problems while generating an access token.

I am getting this error:

**MobileBuySDK.Graph.QueryError.http(403)**

```
    let shopDomain = "mobile-app-velsof.myshopify.com"    
    let apiKey = "2d9bfef9c18942e1b7d132350c52651d"
    let emailSDK = "mbhaisora@velsof.com"
    let passwordSDK = "abc@123"

    let client = Graph.Client(shopDomain: shopDomain, apiKey: apiKey)

    let query = Storefront.buildQuery {
        $0.shop {
            $0.name()
        }
    }


    let task = client.queryGraphWith(query) { response, error in
        if let responseF = response {
            let name = responseF.shop.name
        } else {
            print("Query failed: \(error)")
        }
    }
    task.resume()
```

I didn't understand why I am getting this error. I have followed the same steps as mentioned in Shopify mobile-buy-sdk docs.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

@Knowband Plugins, I believe the code is correct. Just need to check if you are using the correct apiKey?

Comment: Actually, we also tried to use Shopify SDK default key & domain but in this case, we are also getting an error.                                                                                                             let client = Graph.Client(
 shopDomain: "shoes.myshopify.com",
 apiKey:     "dGhpcyBpcyBhIHByaXZhdGUgYXBpIGtleQ"
)                                                                                                                                   We have checked our API key. The same key is working while calling store back panel APIs (Admin Panel) but not working in ios.